# What is the status of the narration "How can Prophet (ﷺ) die since he is a witness"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

This narration is found in Tabaqat Al-Kubra

> أخبرنا محمد بن عمر حدثني مسلمة بن عبد الله بن عروة عن زيد بن أبي عتاب عن أبي سلمة بن عبد الرحمن قال اقتحم الناس على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم في بيت عائشة ينظرون إليه فقالوا كيف يموت وهو شهيد علينا ونحن شهداء على الناس فيموت ولم يظهر على الناس لا والله ما مات ولكنه رفع كما رفع عيسى بن مريم صلى الله عليه وسلم وليرجعن وتوعدوا من قال إنه مات
>
> Narrated Abu Salamah bin ‘Abd al-Rahman: The people rushed to the Prophet, may Allah bless him, in the apartment of ‘Aisha to look at him. They said: “How can he die since he is a witness to us and we are witnesses to other people? … No! by Allah! He has not died; but he has been raised as ‘Eisa ibn Maryam was made to ascend and he will return, and they warned those who said that he had died ... ”
>
> <sup>[Tabaqat al-Kubra 2/271](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9351/2582#p1)</sup>

Is this authentic?

Comment: Just as a remark generally historians have a low standard in accepting narrations. Therefore narrations of a lot of them are not taken -without backup- by default by hadith scholars.

Comment: Even if the narration is authentic, it should be noted that the statement itself is wrong. This was said by confused and sad people at the death of the Prophet.This was a mistake by them until Abu Bakr (RA) corrected them. See: https://sunnah.com/urn/133001

Comment: @TheZ - Brother, I do not think that the statement is wrong. A similar statement was also made by Umar bin Al-Khattaab and said he would strike the head of anyone who says that Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) is dead. I am refuting Qadianis, the main point here is that people believed that Jesus will descend physically before hereafter.